# What is Homomorphic image of a field $F$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

What is Homomorphic image of a field? How to define it? 
Can anyone please make me understand?

I was trying to prove the theorem $F$ can have only two homomorphic image. Then I got this doubt -- **When ker $\phi $ is zero how the homomorphic image of $F$ is $F$?**

Comment: The definition is, it's the image of the field under a homomorphism. So: do you know what field means? do you know what image means? do you know what homomorphism means?

Comment: @GerryMyerson and just to be extra clear, "it's the image of the field under a *ring* homomorphism."

Comment: Yea I know all this terms. But if the homomorphic image of $F$ is $\phi (F)$ then how do you prove the theorem. How $\phi (F) = F$ when ker$\phi$ = 0

Comment: I recommend thinking about the possibilities for $\phi(1)$ (and the consequences for $\phi(\alpha)$ of the value of $\phi(1)$).

Comment: @cmi If $\ker\phi=0$, $\phi$ is injective, hence an isomorphism onto its image.

Comment: How injective function becomes isomorphic? How do you prove surjectivity?@Ben West

Comment: Yea $\ phi (1) $ is unity but how it is proved that $ \ phi $ is onto homomorphic as well.@Gerry Myerson

Comment: Just to clarify the logic of this problem, your goal in this problem is to *assume* that $R$ is a ring and to *assume* that $\phi : F \to R$ is a surjective ring homomorphism, and then to use these assumptions to *prove* that either $R$ is the trivial ring or $\phi$ is injective.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: what are the ideals of the field $F$? If $\phi: F \rightarrow R$ is a homomorphism and $I \subseteq R$ is an ideal, what can you say about $\phi^{-1}(I)$?

Comment: But I was to prove that any homomorphism of a field F is either trivial  or proper..@Badam Baplan...How do I conclude from your derivation?

Answer (score 1):

Well,

A ***homomorphic image*** of a field $F$ is $\phi(F)$, where

$\phi:F \to R \tag 1$

is a *ring* homomorphism 'twixt $F$ and some ring $R$; the definition really depends on the existence of such $R$, which is required for the existence of $\phi$.  So to *define* $\phi(F)$, the existence of $R$ must be stipulated, as then the existence of such $\phi:F \to R$.

Since any such $\phi$ is a ring homomorphism, we have

$F/\ker \phi \simeq \phi(F), \tag 2$

so we inquire into the nature of $\ker \phi$; it is an ideal in $F$; but the only non-trivial ideal $I \subset F$ must satisfy

$1_F \subset I, \tag 3$

for if

$0 \ne s \in I, \tag 4$

then

$\exists s^{-1} \in F, \tag 5$

whence

$1_F = s^{-1}s \in I, \tag 6$

hence for every $f \in F$,

$f = f1_F \in I \Longrightarrow I = F; \tag 7$

since the only non-trivial ideal in $F$ is $F$ itself, if $\phi$ is non-trivial we must have

$\ker \phi =\{0\}; \tag 8$

otherwise

$\ker \phi = F \Longrightarrow \phi(f) = 0,\; \forall f \in F, \tag 9$

and $\phi$ is trivial.  With (8), $\phi$ is *injective*, which in turn implies that

$\phi:F \simeq \phi(F) \subset R, \tag{10}$

and $R$ must contain a "copy" of $F$ as a subring.

Comment: But I was to prove that any homomorphism of a field F is either trivial  or proper..@Robert Lewis...How do I conclude from your derivation?

Comment: When ker $\ phi $ is zero how the homomorphic image of $F$ is $F$?@Robert Lewis

Answer (score 0):

Consider the homomorphism $\phi: F\rightarrow R$, where $F$ is a field and $R$ is a ring. The unit element $1_F$ of $F$ is mapped either to the zero element $0_R$ of $R$ or to a nonzero element $r\in R$. Note that $\ker\phi$ is an ideal of $F$. Note that $\phi(0_F)=0_R$ holds in each case.

In the first case, for any element $a\in F$, $\phi(a)=\phi(a\cdot 1_F) =\phi(a)\cdot\phi(1_F) = \phi(a)\cdot 0_R=0_R$, since the zero element of a ring is always absorbing; i.e., for each $r\in R$, $r\cdot 0_R = r\cdot (r+(-r)) = r^2-r^2=0_R$, similar $0_R\cdot r=0_R$. Thus $\ker\phi=F$ and hence the homomorphic image is $\{0_R\}$.

In the second case, let $\phi(1_F)=r\ne 0_R$. Then $\ker\phi$ is properly contained in $F$. But the only ideals of $F$ are the zero ideal $\{0_F\}$ and $F$ itself. Thus $\ker\phi = \{0_R\}$ and so the homomorphic image is $\phi(F)$ which is isomorphic to $F$.

Comment: I did not get your last line. $ \phi$ should be injective. How do you claim that it will be isomorphic?@Wuestenfux

Comment: If a ring homomorphism has kernel $\{0\}$, the mapping is injective.

Comment: There is an injective homomorphism between preimage and image.

Comment: So the $ \phi (F) $ may be a proper subset of $F$?@Wuestenfux

Comment: No, the mapping from $F$ to $\phi(F)$ is injective and also clearly surjective.

Comment: If the $ \phi $ maps from $F$ to $F$.Then the $ \phi (F) $ may be a proper subset of $F$?@Wuestenfux

Answer (score 0):

The homomorphic image of $F$ under $\phi$ doesn't have to be $F$, even if the kernel of $\phi$ is trivial.

For example, let $I$ be the ideal in the integers generated by $5$, and let $J$ be the ideal in the Gaussian integers (that's ${\bf Z}[i]$) generated by $2+i$. Then $F_1={\bf Z}/I$ and $F_2={\bf Z}[i]/J$ are fields, and the map $\phi:F_1\to F_2$ induced by $\phi(1+I)=1+J$ is a surjective field homomorphism with trivial kernel, but $F_1\ne F_2$.

The two fields are isomorphic, though.