# The only non-trivial Homomorphic images of a field $F$ is $F$-------Is the statement true?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

The only non-trivial Homomorphic images of a field $F$ is $F$-------Is the statement true?

How we can prove or disprove it. I know that a field does not contain any non trivial proper ideal.  and Unity will be mapped to unity itself. But with these two statements I can not progress.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: This has been answered a few minutes ago. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2977156/what-is-homomorphic-image-of-a-field-f/2977632#2977632

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Given a field $F$ and a homomorphism $F\to R$, the homomorphism is either injective (in which case the image is isomorphic to $F$), or it isn't. Show that if it isn't injective, then it's trivial.

Comment: Yea...I know it's ker $ \phi$ will be zero or whole $F$ But when ker $ \phi$ is zero how the function becoming isomorphic. It should be injective only. @Arthur

Comment: @cmi An injective homomorphism isn't necessarily an isomorphism, because it might not be surjective. This is true. But that's not what's asked about here. You're asked about the _image_ of the homomorphism. And any homomorphism is surjective onto its image.

Comment: how then homomorphic image would be $F$..It should be rather $ \phi (F)$?@Arthur

Comment: @cmi Some times we are a bit loose on the distinction between isomorphism and equality. I suspect that that's what happening here.

Comment: I did not get you. Can you please explain?@Arthur

Comment: Is the statement true or not?@Arthur

Comment: So the $ \phi (F) $ may be a proper subset of $F$?  when $F$ is a field and $ \phi$ is a homomorphism.@Arthur

Comment: @cmi If $\phi$ is any injective homomorphism, then $F$ and $\phi(F)$ are isomorphic. There are _scarily many_ different possible $\phi(F)$, because there are scarily many different possible rings $R$ and injective homomorphisms $\phi:F\to R$ out there. But they are all isomorphic. So _essentially_ they are all the same. That's what they mean when they say there is only one non-trivial homomorphic image of $F$. And yes, I suspect it's possible to construct an example where $\phi(F)$ is a proper subset of $F$, but it doesn't really matter. It's isomorphic to $F$ anyways.

Comment: Now my confusion is clear..@Arthur

Comment: @cmi Actually, we have an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2278161/15500). There are fields which are isomorphic to strict subfields of themselves. For instance, given a field $F$, the field $F(x)$ of rational functions in the variable $x$ with coefficients from $F$ is isomorphic to the field $F(x^2)$ of rational functions in the variable $x^2$, which is a strict subfield. The homomorphism $F(x)\to F(x)$ given by $1\mapsto 1, x\mapsto x^2$ is injective, and not surjective.